# My overriden paint method is not getting called

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, paint

I have a JPanel that is meant to act as a HUD for my game, naturally, I have overridden the paint method to do my own custom display, this does get called, but only upon resizing or maximizing, minimizing the frame, and not when my game loop tells it to repaint(). It seems particularly strange to me on account of my two other panels being repainted completely fine.

Here is my HUD class:

```
package base;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class HUD extends JPanel {

    private Shiphud[] shiphuds;

    public HUD(Ship[] ships) {
        shiphuds = new Shiphud[ships.length];
        this.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        for (int i = 0; i < shiphuds.length; i++) {
            shiphuds[i] = new Shiphud(ships[i]);
            this.add(shiphuds[i]);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        for (int i = 0; i < shiphuds.length; i++) {
            shiphuds[i].repaint();
        }
    }
    public void run() {
            repaint();
    }
    private class Shiphud extends JPanel {

        private Ship ship;

        public Shiphud(Ship ship) {
            this.ship = ship;
        }
        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            if (ship != null) {
                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
                int fullbar = (int) (this.getWidth() * 0.8);

                g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                g.fillRoundRect(getWidth() / 10, getHeight() / 10,
                        (int) ((ship.energy / 1000) * fullbar), getHeight() / 6, 10, 10);

                g.setColor(Color.blue);
                g.fillRoundRect(getWidth() / 10, (int) (getHeight() * 0.4),
                        (int) ((ship.fuel / 1000) * fullbar), getHeight() / 6, 10, 10);

                g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
                g.fillRoundRect(getWidth() / 10, (int) (getHeight() * 0.6),
                        (int) ((ship.ammo / 1000) * fullbar), getHeight() / 6, 10, 10);

                g.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
                g.fillRoundRect(getWidth() / 10, (int) (getHeight() * 0.8),
                        (int) ((ship.special / 1000) * fullbar), getHeight() / 6, 10, 10);
                System.out.println("here" + System.currentTimeMillis());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It gets called in my Game classes update along with my other two panels

```
public void update() {
  ...
    display.run();
    display2.run();
    hud.run();
}
```

Which gets called by my JFrame

```
public void runFrame() {
    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            gameLoop();
        }
    };
    thread.start();
}
public void gameLoop() {
    while (true) {
        long beginTime = System.nanoTime();
        game.update();
        long timeTaken = System.nanoTime() - beginTime;
        long timeLeft = (UPDATE_PERIOD - timeTaken) / 1000000;  // in milliseconds
        if (timeLeft < 10) {
            timeLeft = 10;   // set a minimum
        }
        try {
            // Provides the necessary delay and also yields control so that other thread can do work.
            Thread.sleep(timeLeft);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        }
    }
}
```

Been trying to figure this for a long time now, and I just don't get it, any help would be highly appreaciated

Comment: First of all, it's much better to override paintComponent() method [see docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent(java.awt.Graphics)).
Second, for quick look i don't see any mistakes in code, are you sure, that if condition in paint is really satisfied and ship is not null? Did you try to debug that?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I've tried using paintComponent now to no avail, and yes, the if condition is always satisfied.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Comment: One more thing I found, but it not solve your problem, it's just speed optimization. Do not extends `JPanel` it takes unnecessary overhead, it's fine for you just to extends `JComponent`.
Anyway, so if you'll put some `System.out.println(...)` before if statement into the Shiphud's paint method it's called only on resize, etc..?

Comment: That's correct, within, and outside the if statement, you'll see the System.out

Comment: Alright, surprisingly it turns out using JComponent instead was the key, along with  Gnons suggestion this makes it work properly, I'll post the corrected code in 8 hours, when stackoverflow lets me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPanel is a lightweight container.  [In order for it's children to get painted, you need to call super.paint(g) in the overridden paint() method.](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/#lw)

Answer (score 4):

**Do not override the `paint` method in Swing.**

Override `paintComponent` instead.

Then you don't have to call `paint` or `repaint` for your subcomponents - this will be done automatically.

Comment: painting from BackGround task by defalut required repaint(), if there isn't EDT

Comment: @mKorbel: You are right - I meant, in the `paintComponent` method these are not necessary.

Comment: I'm alone or what's going on, mixing AWT & Swing marked as correct answer, really time to stop drinking here +1

Answer (score -1):

Alright guys, thanks for your help, in the end it required a combination of all your solutions to get it to work, what surprised me most was that it needed to be a JComponent for it to repaint properly. Here's the code that works

```
package base;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class HUD extends JPanel {

    private Shiphud[] shiphuds;

    public HUD(Ship[] ships) {
        shiphuds = new Shiphud[ships.length];
        this.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        for (int i = 0; i < shiphuds.length; i++) {
            shiphuds[i] = new Shiphud(ships[i]);
            this.add(shiphuds[i]);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        for (int i = 0; i < shiphuds.length; i++) {
            shiphuds[i].repaint();
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        repaint();
    }

    private class Shiphud extends JComponent {

        private Ship ship;

        public Shiphud(Ship ship) {
            this.ship = ship;
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            if (ship != null) {
                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
                int fullbar = (int) (this.getWidth() * 0.8);

                g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                g.fillRoundRect(getWidth() / 10, getHeight() / 10,
                        (int) ((ship.energy / 1000) * fullbar), getHeight() / 6, 10, 10);

                g.setColor(Color.blue);
                g.fillRoundRect(getWidth() / 10, (int) (getHeight() * 0.4),
                        (int) ((ship.fuel / 1000) * fullbar), getHeight() / 6, 10, 10);

                g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
                g.fillRoundRect(getWidth() / 10, (int) (getHeight() * 0.6),
                        (int) ((ship.ammo / 1000) * fullbar), getHeight() / 6, 10, 10);

                g.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
                g.fillRoundRect(getWidth() / 10, (int) (getHeight() * 0.8),
                        (int) ((ship.special / 1000) * fullbar), getHeight() / 6, 10, 10);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Cheers dudes!